# How to insert a local image into an ioslide presentation in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ioslides

This may be impossibly simple but not finding anything that lays out in direct enough fashion. So I have a lengthy string of code and upon using ggsave (look below) produces the desired chart in My Documents folder.  What would I put after this in order to have the Figure 2.png to show up on the second slide? At the moment, when I knit it says, "## Saving 7.5 x 4.5 in image".

```
  ggsave("Figure 2.png",Figure6UnEmploymentChart)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use ggsave in an rmarkdown ioslides presentation. If you want to use the same ggplot figure twice just print(my_ggplot) twice

Comment: @RichardTelford, make this a proper answer so you can get credit for it. Feeling a bit stupid right now. I just knew it was something more involved than print.